# All Test cases are passing locally/maven build is success after committing into repository bamboo build is failing due to test cases are failing

Tags: maven, bamboo

When i build in eclipse using maven, build is success and all test cases are passing. After pushing code changes to repository and try to build using bamboo test some test cases are failinga and build is also failing.

I have tried locally to build using below commands then also build is success
mvn -Dsurefire.runOrder=random clean test
mvn -Dsurefire.runOrder=reversealphabetical clean test

Comment: Add the build log to your question.

Comment: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.20:test (default-test) on project mpe: There are test failures.
[ERROR] Please refer to /proj/bamboo/agent-1/xml-data/build-dir/NEW-JOB1/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date]-jvmRun[N].dump, [date].dumpstream and [date]-jvmRun[N].dumpstream.

Comment: You have test failures check the test reports for the failure reason.

Comment: But these test cases are passing in local in eclipse and if we see reports for the failure reason fixing is difficult

Comment: Eclipse and maven works differently, do your maven build works locally not in eclipse but in command prompt/terminal using maven?

Comment: I used command prompt there also build is success.

Comment: finally found the issue, the issue is time zone issue. For some test cases using timestamp to store in DB and  while querying from DB this timestamp is not matching. locally build is success and in bamboo is failing because bamboo time zone is Australia and local machine is India time zone. Thanks!! @seenukarthi